# Is it ever ok to remove the original license from a file

Tags: licensing

I have a library I maintain. It is a java library that I originally forked from someone else. They added a BSD license statement to the top of EVERY file. Including files that have no real logic.. Like files that only have a property, and a getter & setter for the property.

For example:

```
public class Boy {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

As this library grows sometimes I have to add new properties to the existing files and add new getters and setters to go along with them. This is boring so I wrote some code that will auto generate all of these (lets call them DataObjects). There are literally 1000s of these DataObjects.

I release all my code under Apache 2.0 Since my script is now generating from scratch all of these DataObjects is it OK for me to license these DataObjects as Apache 2.0 with the original creators name removed, or do I have to make sure to leave the license intact for what they created making sure to only add new properties with getters and setters to those files?

Please note I have no intentions of removing their name or license from files that actually contain logic, Im only interested in these DataObjects

Comment: Probably not, unless you have written permission from the original authors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, let's look at what [the BSD license itself says](http://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-2-Clause):

> Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
>
> 1. Redistributions of source code **must retain the above copyright notice**, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
> 2. Redistributions in binary form **must reproduce the above copyright notice**, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.

Retaining or reproducing the copyright notice is literally the only thing the license requires of you*, so I think it's fairly safe to assume that you should not remove it (unless of course you have express written permission from the original author). Even if this license wasn't legally binding, it might not reflect well on you or your project if you did remove it.

I would just give your script a list of files the original author wrote so it can automagically regenerate the original license statement on them, then use your preferred Apache one on all the new files unique to your project. As far as I know, there's nothing wrong with adding Apache-licensed code alongside BSD-licensed code, since the BSD isn't one of those "infectious" licenses.

Edit: Just to be thorough, the technically correct answer to your question in its most general form is "Yes, if that license does not prohibit it." Most of the open source licenses I know of have a provision specifically saying you cannot do this, so in practice the answer will almost always be "No", but if for some reason you were modifying [WTFPL](http://www.wtfpl.net/)'d software instead, then you would be totally free to throw out the existing license statements.

<sub>*You didn't specify which BSD license, so I'm assuming the 2-clause version for this answer. The additional clause in [the 3-clause version](http://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause) probably doesn't affect your question.</sub>

Comment: As a follow up what if I were to redo the DataObject?

I found a project called lombok that allows me to generate getters and setters using annotations. would that be considered a new file or still same rules apply?

Comment: Here is the original: https://github.com/yavijava/yavijava/blob/gradle/src/main/java/com/vmware/vim25/AlarmState.java

What my new version would be like: https://gist.github.com/michaelrice/e8085f5e5f8826cdbbc1

Comment: It gets a bit murky when trying to distinguish "new code" from "heavily modified version of the other guy's code", but what I would personally do is write *both* his and your license statements at the top, while changing yours to say "modified by" or "regenerated by" with a later date to make it perfectly clear what happened. Some open-source licenses actually require you to do something like this (eg zlib/png has "Altered source versions must be plainly marked as such").